# What's the point of using explicit data types in PDO::bindValue()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, placeholder, bindvalue

What's the point of using explicit data types in `PDO::bindValue()`?

For example in either of the following forms there would be an `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'a'`

```
$pdos->bindValue(':Value_For_An_Int_Col', 'a');//default arg for the third and opt par is  PDO::PARAM_INT

$pdos->bindValue(':Value_For_An_Int_Col', 'a', PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need something like

```
SELECT * FROM ... LIMIT :intValues
```

That avoids to enclose the value inside quote, rising a SQL syntax error

Comment: This answer is wrong. Quotes are not needed, even when binding strings.

Comment: pdo will insert quoted parameters and the limit will not work

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure, I tested it. No, it does not insert quoted parameters. Could this be a version issue? You might have been right in the past, although I don't think so. To be more verbose: You do not need to specify the data types in PDO::bindValue() explicitly for it to work just fine with string and integer parameters.